# How to update a cocos2d-iphone v2 project to cocos2d-iphone v3?

Tags: cocos2d-iphone

I have installed cocos2d-iphone v2.x and v3 in my mac, and I want to update an old project written in v2.x to v3, so what should I do? thanks.

Comment: Same as before: replace v2 files with v3, update Xcode project, fix dozens if not hundreds of compile errors before you get to fixing bugs caused by upgrading. There is no step-by-step guide since too much has changed going from v2 to v3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A lot has changed between the two (ex CCActions). As far as I know there are no easier ways than copy pasting and rewriting it.

Answer (score -2):

Just install v3 and copy the files from the v2 project over into the v3 project's folder.